# How would REST handle post-processing / including relevant resources?

Tags: web-services, rest, cpu-architecture

I have a web service for a forum, and I have the following two resources:

- /threads/frontpage, returns all the posts that belong on the front page of my site
- /users/1, users/2, etc. returns users specified by the number.

And I want to make it so the user can ask for "all the threads on the frontpage, plus all the users that posted to those threads".

Normally I would separate it out into multiple requests, but that takes more time.

My only thought is to make a URL like this:

/threads/frontpage?includePostingUsers=true

In a way, it's taking the original result, and then using it to include additional info, in this case, the users that posted the threads.

But that doesn't seem very RESTful. There's a verb in there, and it just feels awkward. How would I do this RESTfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a verb in a query parameter is not necessary un-RESTful. I would say that it is common (and more important) to have clean resources and verbs, but to include more involved functionality into query parameters, as you would do with `?includePostingUsers=true`.

Apigee published a nice pragmatic booklet on Crafting Restful APIs:

- [Web API Design – Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf) (PDF), and a related video with real world observations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpAhXa12xvU#t=39m

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It still seems awkward though. Right now my application is looking at having 8 or 9 "&includeXXX=true" for its main query, which is a bit silly. It would be nice to bake that query into the webservice. Is there a reason not to do this?

Comment: @Verdagon, well it really depends. If you have typical things like `page=...` or some `search=...` filters, I think those types of query arguments are quite common and RESTful (you slice your way through a set of resources).

Comment: yeah, that would make sense, except the includeXXX=true are to expand the set of resources, not to constrain it. And it's to sometimes get different resources than the original collection has (we started with /threads but the request is also returning users, in this case).

id imagine REST would have the restriction that anything starting with /threads? would need to return threads, and nothing else. but this is not good enough for my web service, which needs to cut down on requests...

Comment: @Verdagon, about */threads but the request is also returning users* ... Thinking about it in a pragmatic way... I think you can sometimes include more information than just a root resource, e.g. in case of one-to-many relations, where you sometimes want to include the referenced object as a whole, not just its key, mostly for convenience. I can recommend the PDF and the video I mention in my answer, they helped me structure some APIs.

Comment: Wow, that PDF was pretty awesome. The chattiness section addressed my needs perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show `?includePostingUsers=true` in url then use Post request.
And why don't you just pass parameter like

```
/threads/frontpage?uid=1
```